# Detect the Zeroless Numbers

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence

Zeroless numbers are numbers that do not contain **0** as one of their decimal digits.

Given an integer **K**, return the **K**th zeroless number. **K** will be non-negative if you choose **0**-indexing, or positive if you choose **1**-indexing instead. Note that this is OEIS [A052382](https://oeis.org/A052382).

This is code golf, so the shortest code in bytes wins.

### Test cases

1-indexed:

```
1 -> 1
2 -> 2
9 -> 9
10 -> 11
16 -> 17
100 -> 121
```

0-indexed:

```
0 -> 1
1 -> 2
8 -> 9
9 -> 11
15 -> 17
99 -> 121
```

Comment: Converting `n` to bijective base 10 is fundamentally the same as counting in bijective base `B`, so by the standards of PPCG this is a duplicate.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I wouldn't say this is a duplicate, since here much simpler approaches are possible, like counting up and discarding numbers containing a 0 (and seeing different ways to check if a number contains a 0 is interesting by itself)

Comment: @Leo, that approach is possible in the other question too.

Comment: @PeterTaylor it may be possible, but it is not competitive there. Of the answers I can understand in the other question, none use this approach. The vast majority of them are based on cartesian product, which could also be applicable here but currently seems inferior to the other approaches.

Comment: The way I see it is, convert k (zero indexed) into base 9, in the string of digits add 1 to each (and interpret the string as a number in base 10). That seems to be an efficient way time-wise, but won't necessarily make shorter code, depending on the language's features, so brute force may be shorter...

Comment: @Heimdall this doesn't work, e.g. `99` is `120` in base 9, so your method would yield `231`. what works is converto the 1-indexed k into base 9, and starting from the most significant digit, replace every `0` you encounter with a `9` and then subtract 1 from the group of digits to the left of your current digit.

Comment: @FelixPalmen I see the flaw in my method, it doesn't give numbers that begin with 1. I should use a hybrid system where the most significant digit is is base 10 and the rest of the number is in base 9 (but then I wouldn't be able to use a built-in base converter if there is one in whichever language I go for, I would have to write my own). Then leave the most significant digit alone and add 1 to all other digits (if any). Of course, that would need 1-indexed k.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Your method is good though, applied carefully. You could just subtract 1 from the digit to the left rather than the group because it's not going to be 0 since you're parsing from left (from the most significant digit. But sometimes you'll create more zeroes because you'll subtract 1 from 1 (which I guess you'll ignore if that 1 was the most significant digit, like with k=1). So those additional zeroes will have to be dealt with, too, maybe immediately, and continue to parse the number after dealing with the additional zero, or parse the number again.

Comment: For example, k=66348, in base 9 it is 111010. First zero is the fourth digit, so it becomes 110910. Continue parsing the number, the next zero is the sixth (last) digit, we get 110909. Because we created more zeroes, we do another parse (or we have remembered where they were, positions 3 and 5). We get 109909, 109899, next parse, 099899; as it's the most significant number that became 0, we just drop it -> 99899. Or if newly created zeroes are dealt with immediately, it's just one parse: find first zero on position 4, 111010 -> 110910 -> 109910 -> (0)99910, find next zero, -> 99909 -> 99899.

Comment: @Heimdall the latter is the algorithm my submission uses ;) This **is** effectively "subtracting `1` from the group of digits to the left" with the special rule that for the most significant digit only, `0` isn't wrapped to `9` but "cut off" instead. Of course, doing multiple adjustment passes would work as well, didn't think of that. I might check whether it buys me bytes :)

Comment: @WheatWizard This can't be a duplicate. **If** you solve this with a base conversion, adjusting the resulting digits is quite a bit more complex than in the linked challenge. Also, as already commented, other solutions than a base conversion are possible and, depending on the language, superior here.

Comment: @felixpalmen I disagree.  I think this is a duplicate.  I'm quite tired of this general attitude that nothing is a duplicate because of minor differences in the approach of language X.  Your free top vote to reopen but I'm not changing my vote.

Comment: @WheatWizard I'm quite tired of people spoiling challenges because of faint similarities. The differences here are substantial.

Answer (score 28):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
ḃ9Ḍ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjmbLhzt6/h/dc7jd/f9/Qx0FIx0FSx0FQwMgNgPRBgA)

#### How it works

```
ḃ9Ḍ  Main link. Argument: n (1-based index)

ḃ9   Convert n to bijective base 9.
  Ḍ  Convert the result from base 10 to integer.
```

Comment: whoa this is actually genius +1

Comment: Langs with 'monads' and 'bijectives' and 'trilithiums' make me feel like a doofus.

Comment: I'm sorry if this is old news and is addressed elsewhere, i'm new, but wouldn't that be 3 _characters_?

Comment: @RobbieMckennie Jelly, as with several other golfing language, has [its own code page](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page) so that each character is only one byte long. This program would be E7 39 C1 (invalid in UTF-8.)

Comment: Aaaahh got you.

Answer (score 13):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 35 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:n and~-n%9+1+f(~-n/9)*10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcYxCoAgGAbQuU7xL4FmkbopdBjDLKE@RVxaurr1ppefeibo1sJ6uXvzjmBBDv6dMRihRGD/FsNHJVtIhUARVByOnWkpue27XCIqYaLAwNsH)

One indexed.

Comment: `lambda n:int(str(n),11)` is shorter.

Comment: @J843136028 That gives outputs containing zeroes.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 50 bytes

```python
n=input()
i=0
while n:i+=1;n-=1-('0'in`i`)
print i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P882M6@gtERDkyvT1oCrPCMzJ1UhzypT29bQOk/X1lBXQ91APTMvITNBk6ugKDOvRCHz/39DAwA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 10 bytes

```
⌠$'0@cY⌡╓N
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8//9RzwIVdQOH5MhHPQsfTZ3s9/@/oQEA)

Explanation:

```
⌠$'0@cY⌡╓N
⌠      ⌡╓N  nth number (starting with i=0) where
 $            string representation of i
  '0@cY       does not contain 0
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 31 bytes

```hs
(filter(all(>'0').show)[0..]!!)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P81WIy0zpyS1SCMxJ0fDTt1AXVOvOCO/XDPaQE8vVlFR839uYmaegq1CQVFmXomCikJuYoFCmgJI1tDAIPY/AA)

---

**32 bytes**

```hs
(l!!)
l=(+).(10*)<$>0:l<*>[1..9]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P81WI0dRUZMrx1ZDW1NPw9BAS9NGxc7AKsdGyy7aUE/PMvZ/bmJmnoKtQkFRZl6JgopCbmKBQppCtIGenqGBQex/AA) One-indexed.

---

**33 bytes**

```hs
(l!!)
l=0:[10*a+b|a<-l,b<-[1..9]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P81WI0dRUZMrx9bAKtrQQCtRO6km0UY3RyfJRjfaUE/PMjb2f25iZp6CrUJBUWZeiYKKQm5igUKaQrSBnp6hgUHsfwA)

---

**34 bytes**

```hs
(l!!)
l=0:do a<-l;take 9[10*a+1..]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P81WI0dRUZMrx9bAKiVfIdFGN8e6JDE7VcEy2tBAK1HbUE8v9n9uYmaegq1CQVFmXomCikJuYoFCmkK0gZ6eoYFB7H8A)

---

**37 bytes**

```hs
f 0=0
f n=mod(n-1)9+1+10*f(div(n-1)9)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P03BwNaAK00hzzY3P0UjT9dQ01LbUNvQQCtNIyWzDCKg@T83MTNPwVahoCgzr0RBRSE3sUAhTSHaQE/P0MAg9j8A)

Answer (score 5):

### [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 20 bytes

**19 bytes code + 1 for `-p`.**

Uses 1-indexing.

```perl
0while$_-=++$\!~0}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/9@gPCMzJ1UlXtdWW1slRrHOoLb6/39DA4N/@QUlmfl5xf91CwA)

Answer (score 5):

## Javascript (ES7), 23 Bytes

```
f=n=>n&&n--%9+10*f(n/9)
```

Explanation:

```
f=n=>                  //=> syntax
     n&&n--%9          //only with 0 0s
             +10*f(n/9)//^^
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! :)

Comment: Hello! 17B if you use: `n=>+n.toString(9)` (anonymous functions are allowed)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 50 bytes

```python
n=input();v=0
while n:v+=1;n-=min(`v`)>'0'
print v
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P882M6@gtERD07rM1oCrPCMzJ1Uhz6pM29bQOk/XNjczTyOhLEHTTt1AnaugKDOvRKHs/39DAwMA)

Answer (score 4):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 40 bytes

```powershell
param($a)(1..(2*$a)|?{$_-notmatch0})[$a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVRU8NQT0/DSAvIqrGvVonXzcsvyU0sSc4wqNWMVkmM/f//v6UlAA)

Take input `$a`, then construct a range from `1` to `2*$a`. Pull out those elements that regex do `-notmatch` `0`, and then take the `$a`th one thereof. Output is implicit.

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 31 bytes

This is zero-indexed

```hs
(filter(all(>'0').show)[1..]!!)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFRCoAgDADQqywI1I@GHaAuUn4M0ZKmSQrdvvXeSe0KzBKXXXRM3MOjiVmvyiqD7bxfs82IbhiMZEoFFqhPKh1GyFQhwmYRZ2udfD4yHU0mX@sP)

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>16</s> <s>13</s> 14 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to Luis Mendo*

```
E:!tV48-!XA)G)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/39VKsSTMxEJXMcJR013z/39DAwMA)

Explanation:

```
(implicit input)
E                   % double
 :                  % 1:top of stack (so [1, 2, ..., 2n])
  !t                % transpose and dup
    V               % cast to chars
     48-            % subtract 48 (maps numbers to digits)
        !           % transpose
         XA         % Check each column if All are true (nonzero)
           )        % index into array (so we are left with zeroless numbers)
            G)      % paste input and index; TOS is the nth element.
(implicit output)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
DȦ$#Ṫ
```

-2 bytes thanks to Dennis

## Explanation

```
DȦ$#Ṫ  Main link; takes input from STDIN
   #   nfind; get first n matches starting from 0
  $    Get numbers that are zeroless:
D      Digits
 Ȧ     Are all truthy
    Ṫ  Tail; get last element
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/lxDIV5Yc7V/3/b2hgAAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
µNSĀP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//0Fa/4CMNAf//GxoYAAA)

**Explanation**

```
µ       # loop over N until input matches are found
 NS     # split N into list of digits
   Ā    # check if trueish (not zero)
    P   # product
```

or with [Dennis's base conversion trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145165/47066)

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
9.h
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fUi/j/39DAwMA)

Comment: Ahhhh!!! We let Jelly use base conversion before 05AB1E! Noooooooo *o's trail off into the distance...*

Answer (score 3):

## [6502 machine code](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/6502_Assembly) (C64), 124 bytes

```
00 C0 20 FD AE 20 6B A9 A2 05 A9 00 85 FB 85 FC 85 FD A0 10 06 FB 06 14 26 15
90 02 E6 FB A5 FB C9 09 90 04 E9 09 85 FB 26 FC 26 FD 88 D0 E5 A5 FB 95 61 CA
A5 FD 85 15 A5 FC 85 14 D0 CC A5 15 D0 C8 E8 86 FE B5 61 D0 1E A9 09 95 61 86
9E CA B4 61 F0 11 D6 61 D0 0D E4 FE D0 04 E6 FE B0 05 95 61 CA 10 EB A6 9E E8
E0 06 D0 D9 18 A6 FE B5 61 69 30 20 D2 FF E8 E0 06 D0 F4 60
```

**[Online demo](https://vice.janicek.co/c64/#%7B%22controlPort2%22:%22joystick%22,%22primaryControlPort%22:2,%22keys%22:%7B%22SPACE%22:%22%22,%22RETURN%22:%22%22,%22F1%22:%22%22,%22F3%22:%22%22,%22F5%22:%22%22,%22F7%22:%22%22%7D,%22files%22:%7B%22zeroless.prg%22:%22data:;base64,AMAg/a4ga6miBakAhfuF/IX9oBAG+wYUJhWQAub7pfvJCZAE6QmF+yb8Jv2I0OWl+5VhyqX9hRWl/IUU0MylFdDI6Ib+tWHQHqkJlWGGnsq0YfAR1mHQDeT+0ATm/rAFlWHKEOumnujgBtDZGKb+tWFpMCDS/+jgBtD0YA==%22%7D,%22vice%22:%7B%22-autostart%22:%22zeroless.prg%22%7D%7D)**

**Usage:** `sys49152,[n]`, e.g. `sys49152,100`. `n` is **1**-indexed.

Valid values are in the range [1,63999].

#### Explanation:

The common approach to save bytes is to do it iteratively / recursively checking for decimal `0` digits -- this doesn't save bytes on the C64 because there's not even a division instruction available -- just converting to base 9 and adjusting the digits gives a shorter result (still with the need to hand-code a long binary division). Here's the commented disassembly:

```
         00 C0       .WORD $C000        ; load address
.C:c000  20 FD AE    JSR $AEFD          ; consume comma
.C:c003  20 6B A9    JSR $A96B          ; read 16bit number
.C:c006  A2 05       LDX #$05           ; index of last digit in result
.C:c008   .divide:
.C:c008  A9 00       LDA #$00           ; initialize some variables
.C:c00a  85 FB       STA $FB            ; to zero ...
.C:c00c  85 FC       STA $FC
.C:c00e  85 FD       STA $FD
.C:c010  A0 10       LDY #$10           ; repeat 16 times for division
.C:c012   .div_loop:
.C:c012  06 FB       ASL $FB            ; shift remainder left
.C:c014  06 14       ASL $14            ; shift dividend ...
.C:c016  26 15       ROL $15            ; ... left
.C:c018  90 02       BCC .div_nobit     ; highest bit set?
.C:c01a  E6 FB       INC $FB            ; then add one to remainder
.C:c01c   .div_nobit:
.C:c01c  A5 FB       LDA $FB            ; compare remainder ...
.C:c01e  C9 09       CMP #$09           ; ... to 9 (divisor)
.C:c020  90 04       BCC .div_nosub     ; if greater or equal 9 (divisor)
.C:c022  E9 09       SBC #$09           ; subtract 9 from remainder
.C:c024  85 FB       STA $FB
.C:c026   .div_nosub:
.C:c026  26 FC       ROL $FC            ; shift quotient left, shifting in
.C:c028  26 FD       ROL $FD            ; carry if remainder was >= 9
.C:c02a  88          DEY                ; loop counting
.C:c02b  D0 E5       BNE .div_loop      ; and repeat
.C:c02d  A5 FB       LDA $FB            ; load remainder
.C:c02f  95 61       STA $61,X          ; store in current output digit
.C:c031  CA          DEX                ; decrement digit index
.C:c032  A5 FD       LDA $FD            ; copy quotient ...
.C:c034  85 15       STA $15
.C:c036  A5 FC       LDA $FC            ; ... to dividend
.C:c038  85 14       STA $14
.C:c03a  D0 CC       BNE .divide        ; if not zero yet
.C:c03c  A5 15       LDA $15
.C:c03e  D0 C8       BNE .divide        ; repeat division by 9
.C:c040  E8          INX
.C:c041  86 FE       STX $FE            ; remember index of first digit
.C:c043   .adjust_loop:
.C:c043  B5 61       LDA $61,X          ; load digit
.C:c045  D0 1E       BNE .nonine        ; if it's zero, must be changed to 9
.C:c047  A9 09       LDA #$09
.C:c049  95 61       STA $61,X
.C:c04b  86 9E       STX $9E            ; save current index and go back
.C:c04d  CA          DEX
.C:c04e   .sub_loop:
.C:c04e  B4 61       LDY $61,X          ; examine previous digit
.C:c050  F0 11       BEQ .sub_done      ; zero? nothing more to subtract
.C:c052  D6 61       DEC $61,X          ; decrement previous digit
.C:c054  D0 0D       BNE .sub_done      ; not zero -> done
.C:c056  E4 FE       CPX $FE            ; are we at the first digit?
.C:c058  D0 04       BNE .sub_next      ; no: go on
.C:c05a  E6 FE       INC $FE            ; first digit now zero, so increment
.C:c05c  B0 05       BCS .sub_done      ; and done with subtraction
.C:c05e   .sub_next:
.C:c05e  95 61       STA $61,X          ; store 9 to this digit
.C:c060  CA          DEX                ; and go to previous
.C:c061  10 EB       BPL .sub_loop      ; repeat
.C:c063   .sub_done:
.C:c063  A6 9E       LDX $9E            ; load saved digit index
.C:c065   .nonine:
.C:c065  E8          INX
.C:c066  E0 06       CPX #$06           ; reached last digit?
.C:c068  D0 D9       BNE .adjust_loop   ; no -> repeat
.C:c06a  18          CLC
.C:c06b  A6 FE       LDX $FE            ; start output at first digit
.C:c06d   .out_loop:
.C:c06d  B5 61       LDA $61,X          ; load digit
.C:c06f  69 30       ADC #$30           ; add character code `0`
.C:c071  20 D2 FF    JSR $FFD2          ; output character
.C:c074  E8          INX                ; next
.C:c075  E0 06       CPX #$06           ; last digit done?
.C:c077  D0 F4       BNE .out_loop      ; if not, repeat
.C:c079  60          RTS
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth),  <s>9</s>  8 bytes

```
e.f*FjZT
```

**[Verify all the test cases.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=e.f%2aFjZT&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A9%0A10%0A16%0A100&debug=0)**

### Explanation

```
e.f*FjZT   ~ Full program.

 .f        ~ Collect the first Q matches. Uses a variable Z.
     jZT   ~ Decimal digits of Z.
   *F      ~ Product. Can be replaced by .A (all) - Basically checks if all are ≥ 1.
e          ~ End. Get the last element.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 32 bytes

```
[:|p=p+1≈instr(!p$,@0`)|p=p+1}?p
```

### Explanation

```
[:|     FOR a = 1 to <input>
p=p+1   increase p (starts as 0) by 1
≈       WHILE
 instr  the index in 
 (!p$     the string-cast of p
 ,@0`)|   of the string '0' is non-zero
 p=p+1    skip this number in the zero-less sequence
}       WEND, NEXT 
?p      PRINT p
```

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 55 bytes

```
(s=t=1;While[s<=#,If[DigitCount[t++,10,0]<1,s++]];t-1)&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277X6PYtsTW0Do8IzMnNbrYxlZZxzMt2iUzPbPEOb80ryS6RFtbx9BAxyDWxlCnWFs7Nta6RNdQU@1/QFFmXomCQ3q0YSwXnG2ExLZEYhsaIHPMUGQMYv8DAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 24 bytes

```
{(grep {!/0/},^∞)[$_]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WiO9KLVAoVpR30C/VifuUcc8zWiV@Nja/9YKxYmVCkoq8Qq2dgrVaQoq8bVKCmn5RQo2BgqGChYKlgqGpgqWlnbW/wE)

0-indexed.

Comment: `grep(…)` will be one character shorter than `(grep …)`. Otherwise it is basically the same as I came up with. (I used `1..*`)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>50</s> 49 bytes

*1 byte off thanks to @Mr.Xcoder*

```python
lambda n:[k for k in range(2*n)if('0'in`k`)<1][n]
```

0-based.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcExDoAgDADAr3QDnJQNoy9BEjBabdBCCIuvr3f163dhK7hu8qR3PxLw7DNgaZCBGFri69R2YEOo1aiIY45mmYLnILURd0DtnJEf)

Answer (score 1):

## C, 70 bytes

```
i,j,k;f(n){for(i=0;n--;n+=!k)for(k=j=++i;j;j/=10)k=j%10?k:0;return i;}
```

1-indexed

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HU5LCsMgFNx7iteAoKhUu8yr9CLdFFOLSl@LpKuQs1vNrObHMMG8Qmgt6awLRkFyi58qkrdIxiApfypyOMVnr1TCjPnsnZVdc2dvZbZYn@uvEiTcW6IV3o9EQrKNQccwCA86Vsg7BLperEVQiuQRdHxrL0Yx8WUGvtxp0kAaxh2JbG9/)

## C (gcc), 65 bytes

```
i,j,k;f(n){for(i=0;n--;n+=!k)for(k=j=++i;j;j/=10)k=j%10?k:0;n=i;}
```

1-indexed

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HU7LCsMgELz7FduAoKhUe8x26Y/0UgwWlW5D6C3k261mTvNimOjeMbaWbbEVk2K9p@@mMnlk55ANXaoeTqVCxmQsWK4UvO5aBv@ocy9SxqNl/sHnlVlpsQvoGAbjSccAU0Dg@817BGNYn0HHuvViUpNcZpDLkycLbGE80SiO9gc)

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>28</s> 27 bytes

```js
f=n=>n&&--n%9+1+10*f(n/9|0)
```

```html
<input type=number min=1 oninput=o.textContent=f(this.value)><pre id=o>
```

Edit: Saved 1 byte by switching to a numeric result (effectively porting @xnor's Python answer).

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA, 57 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input, `n` from range `[A1]` and outputs the `n`th `0`-indexed zeroless number to the VBE immediate window.

```vb
For i=1To[A1]:j=j+1:While InStr(1,j,0):j=j+1:Wend:Next:?j
```

Answer (score 1):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 39 bytes

```
{for(;c<$1;)c=index(++i,0)?c:c+1;$0=i}1
```

Since this is `AWK` `1`-indexing seemed appropriate.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/Oi2/SMM62UbF0Foz2TYzLyW1QkNbO1PHQNM@2SpZ29BaxcA2s9bw/39DAwMA)

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 45 bytes

```java
int c(int n){return n>0?--n%9+1+c(n/9)*10:0;}
```

1-indexed

Port of [*@xnor*'s Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145163/52210).

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##LY6xDoIwEIZ3nuJCYtJawTI4IKJP4MRoHCqgKcKVtIXEEJ69FsJw/z/cfV@uEaOIVF9jU31d2Qpj4C4kTgGAscLKEpxECyVZEumkaztoBLzyWxThLmUJKwkeU7pP@JlnswPoh1fruQ0flayg80pSWC3x83iCoIse4K30qpV5koG85CfOfTO2rQGKn7F1F6vBxr1nLfFvUBYeQpqtF3OwzOz@)

```java
int c(int n){  // Method with integer as both parameter and return-type
  return n>0?  //  If `n` is larger than 0:
    --n%9      //   Return `(n-1)%9
    +1         //    + 1
    +c(n/9)    //    + recursive call with `(n-1)/9`
     *10       //      multiplied by 10
   :           //  Else:
    0;         //   Return 0
}              // End of method
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <s>68</s> 63 bytes

-8 bytes thanks to @raznagul.

```cs
k=>{int i=0;for(;k>0;)if(!(++i+"").Contains("0"))k--;return i;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5NS8QwEIbP7a8Ye0roB11vEtuLsKcVBA8exEOIaR26m0BmVpHS314niHjIwAzP@z5x1LqY/O7OlgieUpyTvcBaFsSW0cFnxHd4tBgUccIwv76BTTPpjBTP38T@0h2vwd1j4AZkjDDBsC/DuMoCOPRmikmZZeyNxkndqLrGuqp09xADSy@pqq@0XtrWJM/XFADNthtpl7zY2BM7S55ggOC/4Pe6wqGB2wbuGjj0@fWw5Yy4vHUfoLI8R4X/r9BC/H1a9BTPvntJyP6EwatJZVBrU5bFVm77Dw)

---

Don't really want to use this, since it's just a C# port of an existing answer.

**[C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 45 bytes**

```cs
int c(int n){return n>0?--n%9+1+c(n/9)*10:0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY6xasNAEERr6Su2CdzFkn1KJ4skhVsHAi5ShBTHZiMf2Htwu7YxQt8un@wixU4xzLwdlBpjogkPXgQ@U@yTP8JQinoNOAVWQDMr2yGRnhIDv7n3uuandtEs0PCqtc@NW7tunMriUYNzDL/w4QMb0RS4//4Bn3qxGVwWRcZlQ0kUvZDAKzBd4OEO0FTwUkFbQePmczB2ufOXR3rcw33LXM35f4TNiWJ3FaXjchNZ4oGWXykobQOTQTMHre3y87Ecpxs)

Comment: You can save some bytes by removing `j` and decrementing `k` instead.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jq 1.5](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 76 bytes

```
[.,0]|until(.[0]<1;.[1]+=1|if"\(.[1])"|contains("0")then. else.[0]-=1end)[1]
```

Expanded

```
  [.,0]                           # initial state (n, v)
| until(.[0]<1;                   # until we've found n'th number
     .[1]+=1                      #   increment v
   | if "\(.[1])"|contains("0")   #   if v contains 0
     then .                       #   leave state alone
     else .[0]-=1                 #   otherwise decrement n
     end
  )[1]                            # return n'th number found
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcvBCgIhFIXhVwlXSlfxtgii5knMxVBGhlynvNLGZx/H2Rz44Pyfb0c4wQXQAp7H2tadAetbJY5JGmf9Da/GoT9O2OJL3OUOJdojE8@RihRWKH4HMoeQStgLPWGgpxq/3te8cMxUutZUU9KRlsoDv/mvc@WBDQ)