# Smallest Zeroless Base

Tags: code-golf, number, integer, base-conversion

Given a positive integer `n`, output the smallest base `b >= 2` where the representation of `n` in base `b` with no leading zeroes does not contain a `0`. You may assume that `b <= 256` for all inputs.

### Test Cases

```
1 -> 2 (1)
2 -> 3 (2)
3 -> 2 (11)
4 -> 3 (11)
5 -> 3 (12)
6 -> 4 (12)
7 -> 2 (111)
10 -> 4 (22)
17 -> 3 (122)
20 -> 6 (32)
50 -> 3 (1212)
100 -> 6 (244)
777 -> 6 (3333)
999 -> 4 (33213)
1000 -> 6 (4344)
1179360 -> 23 ([12, 9, 21, 4, 4])
232792560 -> 23 ([15, 12, 2, 20, 3, 13, 1])
2329089562800 -> 31 ([20, 3, 18, 2, 24, 9, 20, 22, 2])
69720375229712477164533808935312303556800 -> 101 ([37, 17, 10, 60, 39, 32, 21, 87, 80, 71, 82, 14, 68, 99, 95, 4, 53, 44, 10, 72, 5])
8337245403447921335829504375888192675135162254454825924977726845769444687965016467695833282339504042669808000 -> 256 ([128, 153, 236, 224, 97, 21, 177, 119, 159, 45, 133, 161, 113, 172, 138, 130, 229, 183, 58, 35, 99, 184, 186, 197, 207, 20, 183, 191, 181, 250, 130, 153, 230, 61, 136, 142, 35, 54, 199, 213, 170, 214, 139, 202, 140, 3])
```

Comment: What are the values for ten, eleven, etc. in higher bases you are using? Do they contain zeroes?

Comment: @Stephen The OP talking about the array-based representations of them, not the actual string representation

Comment: @Stephen The values chosen for digits above `9` do not matter, because they are not `0`.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/145157/detect-the-zeroless-numbers).

Comment: This is OEIS [A106370](http://oeis.org/A106370).

Comment: What if builtins can´t do base 1000?

Comment: @Titus That's a good point. I'll limit the base to something reasonable.

Comment: you should probably explicitly say you can't use fractional part numbers (10 = 9.999..., 17000 = 17999.999...)

Comment: Could you add a couple of test cases with larger (>36) outputs?

Comment: @DestructibleLemon Do you mean 17000=16999,999...? Because it's certainly not 17999,999...

Comment: @Shaggy I tested my MATL entry up to `1e6`, and didn't get beyond base `20` at `n=658370`

Comment: The question title is misleading, and perhaps impossible. Don't all bases use zeros? Perhaps it should be "Smallest Base of Zeroless Representation".

Comment: @CJDennis You're reading too much into it.

Comment: @Shaggy I'm still searching for cases where `b > 20`. It's taking a while!

Comment: @Mego: Try 232792560.  It's the lcm of 2,3,...,20, so in every base <= 20 it has a 0 as the least significant digit.

Comment: While the larger test cases are interesting, are we required to handle them? If our language doesn't support extended integers, for example, or at least, not by default?

Comment: @ConorO'Brien By the meta consensus, no.

Comment: @Mego Which meta consensus, for future reference?

Comment: @ConorO'Brien There's not a hard consensus, but the answers to [this question](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8471/45941) all share the same idea that cases where the input and/or output exceed the language's representable range need not be considered.

Answer (score 16):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 6 bytes

```
f*FjQT
```

**[Verify all the test cases.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=f%2aFjQT&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A10%0A17%0A20%0A50%0A100%0A777%0A999%0A1000&debug=0)**

### How it works

```
f*FjQT  ~ Full program.

f       ~ First positive integer where the condition is truthy.
   jQT  ~ The input converted to base of the current element.
 *F     ~ Product. If the list contains 0, then it's 0, else it is strictly positive.
          0 -> Falsy; > 0 -> Truthy.
        ~ Output the result implicitly.
```

Although Pyth's `f` operates on `1, 2, 3, 4, ...` (starting at 1), Pyth treats numbers in base 1 (unary) as a bunch of zeros, so base 1 is ignored.

Comment: Nice abuse of the fact that Pyth's base-1 representation is all-zeroes.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Thanks! I will add an explanation regarding that.

Comment: Pyth isn't the only language whose unary representation uses zeroes as digits *hint* :P

Comment: You wrote `0 -> Falsy; > 0 -> Truthy`. Is that intentional that `0` is both `Truthy` and `Falsy` in that situation?

Comment: @BrianJ There is a `>` sign in front of the second `0`, which means that everything higher than 0 is truthy.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder D'oh, completely missed it the first read. Thanks!

Comment: `.A` (all) would be a bit more natural than `*F`, but this works just as well.

Comment: @isaacg Thanks, thought of that too but it wouldn't change much nonetheless. I was wondering though, why can't I remove the trailing `T` (the error messages when `T` is removed seem quite misleading)?

Comment: `j` allows a single input the way `f` does. On one input, `j` is the join function, which is not what we want here.

Comment: @isaacg Duh right, I forgot about `j`'s overloads >.<

Answer (score 12):

## C,  <s>52</s>  50 bytes

```
i,k;f(n){for(i=2,k=n;k;)k=k%i++?k/--i:n;return i;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fc1BCsIwEAXQfU8RCoWEJthGa4gheBE3Eo0MoaOEuio9eyy61HGW//H/BHULoRSQyUWOYo73zMFrmTy65ETyqYG2PaaNUnBAl6/TMyMDtxTAiY1nQC6quWLrPfIaRV43lxPWkkXeC@F@iyZlS8qOlIGUPSmGlL6jiW5pujX8GexoM4b@Zq39tlXYZ/M9upQX)

## C (gcc),  <s>47</s>  45 bytes

```
i,k;f(n){for(i=2,k=n;k;)k=k%i++?k/--i:n;n=i;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fc1BCsIwEAXQfU8RCoWEJthGa4gheBE3EokMg6MUd6Vnj0GXOs7yP/6fZK4plQIaQ5aklnyfJUSrMVLAoDBiB31/xI0xcKBAEcJagJ7idgaSqlkaUe8x1yjLtrucqNUiy1Gp8FssK1tWdqxMrOxZcayMA098y/Kt6c/gwJtz/Dfv/bdVEZ/N9@haXg)

---

*Two bytes saved thanks to @Nevay's suggestion on @Kevin Cruijssen's answer!*

Comment: The latter version works only by random luck, even if you insist on a specific compiler. And, of course, neither version is really C.

Comment: @AnT it is C.. it will give a lot of warnings but it will compile. as long as you find a compiler that works for your code, you're fine

Comment: 46: `k=k%i` --> `k%=i`, IIRC

Comment: @Blacksilver `k%i` is a ternary-check here. A more readable variant would be `k=(k%i?k:n*++i);` or even more clearly: `if(k%i){k=k;}else{k=n*++i;}`.

Comment: Also, you can golf both by 2 bytes: [`i,k;f(n){for(i=2,k=n;k;)k=k%i++?k/--i:n;return i;}`](https://tinyurl.com/y8szl5vw) and [`i,k;f(n){for(i=2,k=n;k;)k=k%i++?k/--i:n;n=i;}`](https://tinyurl.com/y9fb5m6b). All credit goes to _@Nevay_ who posted this suggestion on [my ported Java 8 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/146357/52210).

Comment: @Felipe Nardi Batista: I'm aware of the fact that CodeGolf rules say "as long as it compiles" and so on. However, the fact that it "compiles" does not in any way prove that it is C. This is not C. Typeless declarations like `i, k;` and `f(n)` existed in ancient versions of C (K&R), but only in the era when `return` required round brackets around its argument. If you want to use K&R with `i,k;`, you also have to use `return(i);`. The above might be gnuc, but not C.

Comment: @AnT Yeah, it's not real, modern (or any other particular era) C, but as long as it compiles with a C compiler, it can be called C here, because on PPCG [a language is defined by its implementation](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7832/whats-the-policy-on-interpreter-bugs/7833#7833).

Comment: @Steadybox: Yes, but how do PPCG rules establish connection between "language" to "its implementation"? Who said that defalt-configured `gcc` compiler is an implementation of C? In fact, everybody knows that it isn't.

Comment: @AnT While a default-configured gcc-compiler doesn't implement the C standard precisely, I think it still is reasonable to call code written for it C. It still is a version of C, even if it's not a standard version.

Comment: @AnT: I've specifically called for tcc a few times.

Comment: Nice.  Note code fails for OP's last 3 test cases with 32-bit `int`.  Certainly has trouble with many values > `INT_MAX`

Comment: @chux Yep, it can't handle inputs larger than `INT_MAX` as is, but [that's okay](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8471/integer-range-defaults-for-challenges).

Answer (score 9):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>56</s> <s>52</s> 48 bytes

```hs
b#n=n<1||mod n b>0&&b#div n b
f n=until(#n)(+1)2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P0k5zzbPxrCmJjc/RSFPIcnOQE0tSTklswzE4UpTyLMtzSvJzNFQztPU0DbUNPqfm5iZZ1tQlJlXopKmYGlp@R8A)

Pretty basic but can't think of any good ways to shorten it

EDIT: Thanks to Laikoni for saving me 4 bytes! Don't know why I never thought of `!!0`. I probably should've tried removing those parentheses but I have vague memories of some weird error when you try to use `||` and `&&` together. Maybe I'm confusing it with the equality operators.

EDIT 2: Thanks @Lynn for shaving another 4 bytes! Don't know how I never knew about `until` before now.

Comment: You beat me by a minute with nearly exactly the same solution. :) `!!0` is shorter than `head` and I think you can drop the parenthesis in `#`.

Comment: The criminally underrated `until :: (a → Bool) → (a → a) → a → a` saves four bytes: `f n=until(#n)(+1)2`

Answer (score 7):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 33 bytes

```
2//.i_/;DigitCount[#,i,0]>0:>i+1&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2ar8d9IX18vM17f2iUzPbPEOb80ryRaWSdTxyDWzsDKLlPbUO2/pjVXQFFmXolDWrShgYFB7H8A)

Answer (score 6):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 7 bytes

```
→V▼MBtN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv5/aFtu/qOmxqJD2/4/apsU9mjaHl@nEr////8bchlxGXOZcJlymXGZcxkacBmacxkZcJkCGQYGXObm5lyWlpYgtgEA)

#### Explanation

```
→V▼MBtN
     tN    list of natural numbers starting from 2
   MB      convert the (implicit) input to each of those bases
 V▼        find the (1-based) index of the first result where the minimum digit is truthy
→          add 1 to this index
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
2b@Ạ¥1#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98oyeHhrgWHlhoq////39DAwAAA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 57 bytes

```python
n=x=input()
b=2
while x:z=x%b<1;b+=z;x=[x/b,n][z]
print b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P8@2wjYzr6C0REOTK8nWiKs8IzMnVaHCqsq2QjXJxtA6Sdu2yrrCNrpCP0knLza6KparoCgzr0Qh6f9/IwA)

This is one byte shorter than a recursive function:

```python
f=lambda n,b=1,x=1:b*(x<1)or f(n,b+(x%b<1),[x/b,n][x%b<1])
```

Comment: BTW this is pretty similar to my solution.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to Adnan

```
1µNвPĀ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f8NBWvwubAo40/P9vCgA)

Comment: 10 bytes: `[¹NÌDŠвPĀ#`

Comment: `1µNвPĀ` works for 6 bytes

Comment: @Adnan I knew it was way too long

Comment: `LB0.å0k` is another method entirely >_>.

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 9 bytes

```
←foΠ`B⁰tN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv5/aFtu/qOmxqJD2/4/apuQln9uQYLTo8YNJX7///835DLiMuYy4TLlMuMy5zI04DI05zIy4DIFMgwMuMzNzbksLS1BbAMA)

### Explanation

```
            -- input N
        tN  -- tail of [1..] == [2..]
←f(    )    -- filter with the following:
    `B⁰     --   convert N to that base
   Π        --   product (0 if it contains 0)
←           -- only keep first element
```

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, <s>61</s> <s>56</s> 54 bytes

```java
n->{int b=2,t=n;for(;t>0;)t=t%b++<1?n:t/--b;return b;}
```

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##hY7BbsIwEETvfMVeKjmiSZO0EKVu6BeUC0fUg20MMoRN5GyQKpRvDw5wrVZar@R9o5k5qouKm9bicXcaTa26Dn6Uw@sMwCFZv1fGwnr63g9gxLQxkuEyhBemI0XOwBoQKhgxXl0nia7yV6pQ7hsvJK1SGVFFL3o@/8q@8ZPe4lhLb6n3CFoOo3x4tb2ug9fT8tK4HZxDHbEh7/Cw/QUVPbps/jqy56TpKWkDohoFJkZk0b3Zvzxn@DvDPxi@YPiS4QXDs5QTcA4557BgI1JOURRci7Is@ZRnzDAbxhs)

**Explanation:**

```java
n->{            // Method with integer as both parameter and return-type
  int b=2,      //  Base-integer, starting at 2
      t=n;      //  Temp-integer, copy of the input
  for(;t>0;)    //  Loop as long as `t` is not 0
    t=t%b++<1?  //   If `t` is divisible by the base `b`
                //   (and increase the base `b` by 1 afterwards with `b++`)
       n        //    Set `t` to the input `n`
      :         //   Else:
       t/--b;   //    Divide `t` by the `b-1`
                //    (by decreasing the base `b` by 1 first with `--b`)
                //  End of loop (implicit / single-line body)
  return b;     //  Return the resulting base
}               // End of method
```

<s>I have the feeling this can be golfed by using an arithmetic approach.</s> It indeed can, with a port of [@Steadybox' C answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/146315/52210), and then golfed by 2 bytes thanks to *@Nevay*.

Old (**61 bytes**) answer:

```java
n->{int b=1;for(;n.toString(n,++b).contains("0"););return b;}
```

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##hY4xb8IwFIR3fsUTky2KldBCFFl071AWxqqDYwwyDc@R/YJUofz21BDW6kn24PvOd3c2V7MMncPz4We0rUkJPo3H2wzAI7l4NNbB7v58CGDFR5ZPLgJKndUh33wSGfIWdoCwhRGX77e7udmW@hii0Kgo7Cl6PAl8WSwaqWxAyj1JzIu51FJHR31EaPQw6imy65s2Rz6Tr8Ef4JJ/iCnn6xuMnGbtfxO5iwo9qS4jalGgsqKUj4H/8hXDXxn@xvA1wzcMrxheFpyBS1hxCWu2ouAcVcWtqOuab3nWDLNh/AM)

**Explanation:**

```java
n->{         // Method with Integer as both parameter and return-type
  int b=1;   //  Base-integer, starting at 1
  for(;n.toString(n,++b).contains("0"););
             //  Loop as long as the input in base-`b` does contain a 0,
             //  after we've first increased `b` by 1 before every iteration with `++b`
  return b;  //  Return the resulting base
}            // End of method
```

Comment: 54 bytes: `n->{int b=2,t=n;for(;t>0;)t=t%b++<1?n:t/--b;return b;}`

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>20</s> 19 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9428/when-can-apl-characters-be-counted-as-1-byte-each/9429#9429)

```apl
1+⍣{~0∊⍺⊥⍣¯1⊢n}≢n←⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM97b@h9qPexdV1Bo86uh717nrUtRTIPbTe8FHXorzaR52L8h61TXjUNxWk9n8alxkA)

As usual, thanks to @Adám for helping out in chat and getting the code to work in TIO. Also, saving 1 byte.

This is tradfn (**trad**itional **f**unctio**n**) body. To use it, you need to assign it a name (which is in TIO's header field), enclose it in `∇`s (one before the name and one in TIO's footer field), and then call it using its name. Since it uses a quad (`⎕`) to take the user's input, it's called as `f \n input` instead of the usual `f input`

#### How?

```apl
1+⍣{~0∊⍺⊥⍣¯1⊢n}≢n←⎕  ⍝ Main function.
                  n←⎕ ⍝ Assigns the input to the variable n
1+⍣{           }≢     ⍝ Starting with 1, add 1 until the expression in braces is truthy
    ~0∊               ⍝ returns falsy if 0 "is in"
        ⊥             ⍝ convert
            ⊢n        ⍝ the input
         ⍣¯1          ⍝ to base
       ⍺              ⍝ left argument (which starts at 1 and increments by 1)
```

The function then returns the resulting base.

Comment: Golfing tip: since `n←⎕` will be a simple number and you need `1` as initial argument to the rest of the code, you can just count the number of elements in `n` (which is 1), by replacing `1⊣` with `≢`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM97b@h9qPexdV1Bo86uh717nrUtRTIPbTe8FHXorzaR52L8h61TXjUNxWk9n8alxkA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 57 bytes

```python
n=m=input()
b=2
while m:c=m%b<1;b+=c;m=(m/b,n)[c]
print b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P8821zYzr6C0REOTK8nWiKs8IzMnVSHXKtk2VzXJxtA6Sds22TrXViNXP0knTzM6OZaroCgzr0Qh6f9/QwMDAwA)

-1 thanks to [Felipe Nardi Batista](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66418/felipe-nardi-batista).
-2 thanks to [Lynn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3852/lynn) (and now this is a dupe of her solution :D)

Comment: [59 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P8821zYzr6C0REOTK8nWiKs8IzMnVSHXztAq2TZXNcnG0DpJ2zbZOtdWI1c/SSdPMzo5lqugKDOvRCHp/39DAwMDAA) by changing `a,b=a+c,d` to `a+=c;b=d`

Comment: I think you can replace `while m>1` by `while m` (and then we’re tied!)

Comment: @Lynn That's why I commented on your solution, it would be exactly the same then.

Comment: [That’s okay!](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/3852)

Comment: @Lynn I already knew :p otherwise I'd have asked you to delete yours.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 8 bytes

```
@ìX e}a2
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=QOxYIGV9YTI=&input=OTk5)

### Explanation

```
@    }a2
```

Return the first number (`X`) to pass the function, starting at `2`

```
ìX
```

Convert the input number to an array of base-`X` digits.

```
e
```

Check if all digits are truthy.

Comment: Won't this fail if the array contains any multiple of `10`?

Comment: @Shaggy My understanding was that, according to OPs comment, that the digits for bases above 9 don't count as zero.

Comment: Ah, I see that now. There's a problem with the phrasing of the challenge, so (or I'm just too tired!).

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>43</s> <s>41</s> 37 bytes

```js
n=>(g=x=>x?g(x%b++?x/--b|0:n):b)(b=1)
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

n=>(g=x=>x?g(x%b++?x/--b|0:n):b)(b=1)

console.log(f(1   )) // 2 (1)
console.log(f(2   )) // 3 (2)
console.log(f(3   )) // 2 (11)
console.log(f(4   )) // 3 (11)
console.log(f(5   )) // 3 (12)
console.log(f(6   )) // 4 (12)
console.log(f(7   )) // 2 (111)
console.log(f(10  )) // 4 (22)
console.log(f(17  )) // 3 (122)
console.log(f(20  )) // 6 (32)
console.log(f(50  )) // 3 (1212)
console.log(f(100 )) // 6 (244)
console.log(f(777 )) // 6 (3333)
console.log(f(999 )) // 4 (33213)
console.log(f(1000)) // 6 (4344)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 11 bytes

```
;.≜ḃ₎¬∋0∧1¬
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASoA1f9icmFjaHlsb2cy//87LuKJnOG4g@KCjsKs4oiLMOKIpzHCrP//Nzc3/1o)

#### Explanation

```
;.≜ḃ₎           The Input represented in base Output…
     ¬∋0        …contains no 0
        ∧1¬     And Output ≠ 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 40 bytes

```
x=>filter(y=>all(digits(y,x)),2..x+3)[0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKL8nP@59m@7/C1i4tM6cktUij0tYuMSdHIyUzPbOkWKNSp0JTU8dIT69C21gz2iD2f0FRZl6JRpqGoabmfwA)

Comment: This is invalid. `2..x` checks for bases in the interval `[2, x)`, hence it fails for test cases `1` and `2`.

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>79</s>  <s>71</s> <s>66</s> <s>63</s> 65 bytes

```r
function(n){while(!{T=T+1;all(n%/%T^(0:floor(log(n,T)))%%T)})T
T}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7LasMwEEX3@grVYDJDByrZjYVd/AtdadcXjiolAiGXWKWFkG93pUAIXVw4zGUO97i6cXXf0SQ/R4h4@jn4YOHupEd9L5@mECDWD7V@BzG4MM9HCPMeImlErGuNZ9RMn9dkl/RhpsUufOQGJDXU0iNtqSNFUpBU1AjaZhCClFLU933hfJCqbzuBzP5@WZPsJ@cXRRGUFE2T02ZVSZe5o6ZFxlxe47mPXA7Bxn06wG0GIjNTgs3zsKHb9cW/UcX5LvNQkYN/DRLP3XVG7q94@XqNFa5/)

This answer is based on Giuseppe's re-arrangement in one single loop.

Saved 8 bytes thanks to JDL, and 6 bytes thanks to Giuseppe.

Comment: You can sub `b` for `T`, which starts out defined as `TRUE == 1`, removing the need for `b=1`. Similarly you can sub `F` for `k` (`F` is `FALSE`)

Comment: I see what you did there. That's a useful one to know!

Comment: 66 bytes using `m%/%T` (integer division) instead of `(m-m%%T)/T`

Comment: [65 bytes](https://tio.run/##VY7LasMwEEX3@grVYDJDByrZjYVd/AtdadcXjiolAiGXWKWFkG93pUAIXVw4zGUO97i6cXXf0SQ/R4h4@jn4YOHupEd9L5@mECDWD7V@BzG4MM9HCPMeImlErGuNZ9RMn9dkl/RhpsUufOQGJDXU0iNtqSNFUpBU1AjaZhCClFLU933hfJCqbzuBzP5@WZPsJ@cXRRGUFE2T02ZVSZe5o6ZFxlxe47mPXA7Bxn06wG0GIjNTgs3zsKHb9cW/UcX5LvNQkYN/DRLP3XVG7q94@XqNFa5/). it was a bit messy but I suspected getting rid of the nested loops would save _something_; I just thought it would be more than 1 byte :(

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
`G@Q_YAA~}@Q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P8HdITA@0tGxrtYh8P9/c3NzAA)

-1 byte thanks to Luis Mendo. This program does not handle testcases bigger than 2^53 (`flintmax`, the maximum consecutive integer representable by a floating point type), as the default datatype is `double` in MATL. However, it should be able to find any arbitrary zeroless base below that number.

```
`            % Do while
 G           %  Push input
  @ _        %  Outputs the iteration number, negate.
     YA      %  Convert input to base given by the iteration number, the negative number is to instruct MATL we want an arbitrary high base with a integer vector rather than the default character vector we know from hexadecimal
       A~    %  If they're not all ones, repeat
         }   % But if they are equal, we finally
          @  %  Push the last base
   Q       Q %  As base 1 makes no sense, to prevent MATL from errors we always increase the iteration number by one.
```

Comment: @LuisMendo I should really start reading the docs better. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for the larger test cases, but I don't know enough about MATL/Matlab to know if that's caused by integer limits or not.

Comment: @Mego I tested my 13 byte version which should be equivalent to the current version up to 1e6, on MATLAB R2017a. What test setup resulted in problems for you?

Comment: The last 2 test cases cause errors.

Comment: @Mego Ah I didn't see those testcases before. This is due to the implementation of MATLs `YA` using doubles internally, so it can only handle inputs up to the maximum consecutive integer representable by a double (see `flintmax`). Does this invalidate the answer? In principle the algorithm works for arbitrary base, I've explicitly worked around another command that would only do up to base 36.

Comment: @Mego Actually, I've spotted your comment on the OP. Thanks for spotting the limitation though, I may want to try and make a MATLAB version that uses arbitrary precision integers.

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>56</s> <s>52</s> <s>51</s> 49 bytes

```
:2&v
1(?\:&:&:@%@,:1%-:
 v~<
l<*v?=2
&v?/:&+1
n>&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/38pIrYzLUMM@xkoNCB1UHXSsDFV1rbgUyupsuHJstMrsbY241Mrs9a3UtA258uzU/v//r1tmZGxkaWBhaWpmZGFgAAA)

The interpreter bugs out on the last 2 testcases.
It only reads the first 16 digits of the input correct and then replaces the rest with other digits.

Answer (score 0):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously),  <s>12</s>  11 bytes

```
╗1⌠╜¡m'0<⌡╓
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASQA2/9hY3R1YWxsef//4pWXMeKMoOKVnMKhbScwPOKMoeKVk///NTA)

Uses [this consensus](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40769640#40769640). Thanks to [Mego](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/45941/mego) for byte-saving help in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte).

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 59+1 bytes

**using builtins**, max base 36:

```php
for($b=1;strpos(_.base_convert($argn,10,++$b),48););echo$b;
```

**no builtins, <s>63</s>60+1 bytes**, any base:

```php
for($n=$b=1;$n&&++$b;)for($n=$argn;$n%$b;$n=$n/$b|0);echo$b;
```

Run as pipe with `-nR` or [try them online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a25caa7efb9ff36eedf301f73f485c4901ce6edd).

Answer (score 0):

## J, 26 bytes

```
]>:@]^:(0 e.]#.inv[)^:_ 2:
```

Would love to know if this can be improved.

The main verb is a the dyadic phrase:

```
>:@]^:(0 e.]#.inv[)^:_
```

which is given the input on the left and the constant 2 on the right.  That main verb phrase then uses J's Do..While construct, incrementing the right y argument as long as 0 is an element of `e.` the original argument in base y.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVqxga6VgoADE/2PtrBxi46w0DBRS9WKV9TLzyqI146ziFYys/mtyKekpqKfZWqkr6CjUWimkFXNxcaUmZ@QrGCnYKqQpGCJzjCEcEzDHDFnGHMIxhuiB8szAPCMDZJ6hgYHBfwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), <s>77</s> 76 bytes

```lua
b=2n=...N=n
while~~N>0 do
if N%b<1then
b=b+1N=n
else
N=N//b
end
end
print(b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P8/ydYoz1ZPT8/PNo@rPCMzJ7Wuzs/OQCElnyszTcFPNcnGsCQjNY8ryTZJ2xCkJjWnOJXLz9ZPXz@JKzUvBYwLijLzSjSSNP///29oYGAAAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Milky Way](https://github.com/zachgates/Milky-Way), 38 bytes

```
^^'%{255£2+>:>R&{~^?{_>:<;m_+¡}}^^^}
```

usage: `./mw base.mwg -i 3`

---

### Explanation

```
code                                 explanation                    stack layout

^^                                   clear the preinitialized stack []
  '                                  push the input                 [input]
   %{                              } for loop
     255£                             push next value from 0..254   [input, base-2]
         2+                           add 2 to the get the base     [input, base]
           >                          rotate stack right            [base, input]
            :                         duplicate ToS                 [base, input, input]
             >                        rotate stack right            [input, base, input]
              R                       push 1                        [input, base, input, 1]
               &{~             }      while ToS (=remainder) is true ...
                  ^                    pop ToS                      [input, base, number]
                   ?{         }        if ToS (=quotient) ...
                     _>:<;              modify stack                [input, base, number, base]
                           m            divmod                      [input, base, quotient, remainder]
                           _+¡         else: output ToS (0) + SoS and exit
                                ^^^   pop everything but the input.
```

I'm sure this can be shortened using a while-loop instead of a for loop, but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

## [Stacked](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked), 23 bytes

```
{!2[1+][n\tb all]until}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcgxCsIwGIDRvaf4OlURIUltf@IguUfMEK2FYqyC6SSePdbt8d45Xu@3oZRPbbzeBT@f84WYUljmPKVvccex2mgMLQc6egSt0IJRdCuUQkSw1v69hhbb9mpbeRo3DexPuLGpeS6ZwCO@yg8)

This increments (`[1+]`) **J** starting from two (`2`) while the base<sub>**J**</sub>  representation of the input has no zeroes (`all` and `until`).

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 52 + 2 (`-pa`) = 54 bytes

```perl
$\=1;while($_&&=$F[0]){$\++;$_=int$_/$\while$_%$\}}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lxtbQujwjMydVQyVeTc1WxS3aIFazWiVGW9taJd42M69EJV5fJQasQiVeVSWmtrb6/38jYyNLAwtLUzMjCwODf/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9QwMDf7rFiQCAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 41 bytes

```ruby
->n{(2..).find{!n.digits(_1).include? 0}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZFNSgNBEIVx6ylG3CSLDF3_VQvjLpcQETQmDMggmiwk5CRuBtFDxdPYyUwMLa6ar16_V_3o98-X9f1b9zG7-lqvFhPfjSfTdjPCuh7Xi6adby7aet4sm9Xr6A7GddM-PK3nj9dV2m57w_fZ7rma3cBtdVlNphWe7wkHogNRoXGhSUE6EB_ICh-kQgQrnHhUtY9NhQqplM2s4Igow9MfA4AF6XGGw05CC5R_xpE8RNF_Uwj6fmGYyAQxDJDNQFmIPF8nIUBKJKInG6Te50SGLJyIOa8EInEMSZyz3B0C1QRIQBGF80VHCeTIPVGdxTSYWd1CJeWdmgeSQ9GRaJ-TGFUjv-NUPBfrf7jr-vMH)

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
Ç╔ü$■╖Ö
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=80c98124feb799&i=1+%0A2+%0A3+%0A4+%0A5+%0A6+%0A7+%0A10+%0A17+%0A20+%0A50+%0A100+%0A777+%0A999+%0A1000+%0A1179360+%0A232792560+%0A2329089562800+%0A69720375229712477164533808935312303556800+%0A8337245403447921335829504375888192675135162254454825924977726845769444687965016467695833282339504042669808000+&a=1&m=2)

Trivial brute force approach

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 12 bytes

```
T NyYaTD Uoo
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJUIE55WWFURCBVb28iLCIiLCIiLCIxMDAiXQ==)

#### Explanation

An iterative solution:

```
T NyYaTD Uoo
              a is command-line input; y is ""; o is 1 (implicit)
T             Loop until
  Ny          Min(y) is truthy:
         Uo     Increment o
     aTD        Convert a to list of digits in that base
    Y           Store that list in y
           o  After the loop, output o
```

---

Alternate solution using filter, also **12 bytes**:

```
@:NaTD_FI2,m
              a is command-line input; m is 1000 (implicit)
         2,m  Range from 2 to 999 (could be 256, but using m is shorter)
       FI     Filter, keeping elements for which this function returns truthy:
   aTD_         Convert a to list of digits in base (function argument)
  N             Get the minimum
@:            Take the first element of the filtered list
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJAOk5hVERfRkkyLG0iLCIiLCIiLCIxMDAiXQ==)